# Voronoi Vertices inside a rectangle

Tags: python, voronoi

I wrote a python code for getting a Voronoi diagram of a region. The region that I consider is a rectangle [-1, 10] by [-1, 10]. Now I am trying to get the Voronoi vertices that lies only inside the rectangle. Can anyone help me in this?

Here is the code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d

# make up data points
points = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(5,2))
print(points)

# compute Voronoi tesselation
vor = Voronoi(points)

# plot
voronoi_plot_2d(vor, show_vertices=False, line_colors='black',line_width=2, line_alpha=1, point_size=10)

# colorize
for region in vor.regions:
    if not -1 in region:
        polygon = [vor.vertices[i] for i in region]
        plt.fill(*zip(*polygon),alpha=0.4)

# fix the range of axes
plt.xlim([-1,11]), plt.ylim([-1,11])

print(vertices)
print(vor.vertices)
plt.show()
```

Also can we get the points of intersection of the Voronoi polygonal lines with the square? I mean I want to know the red circled points in the image below. Is there any way?

[image: Voronoi]

I want to know the Voronoi vertices only inside the square and the point of intersections of the Voronoi regions with the square.